# Delphi - Invalid data type for 'FormVersion'

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I get this error every time when I am trying to set at design time from the Delphi IDE an icon to a form. The stack generated by MadExcept

```
exec. date/time   : 2010-11-04 05:55
version           : 15.0.3953.35171
compiled with     : Delphi XE
madExcept version : 4.0.7
callstack crc     : $c7c5f021, $8136ffbf, $ad918da0
exception number  : 2
exception class   : ERegistryException
exception message : Invalid data type for 'FormVersion'.

main thread ($96c):
500e7157 +023 rtl150.bpl     Registry         174   +1 ReadError
500e7ec9 +069 rtl150.bpl     Registry         556   +8 TRegistry.ReadString
500e90b4 +070 rtl150.bpl     Registry        1069   +7 TRegIniFile.ReadInteger
18ce1096 +02a rxctl140.bpl   rxAppUtils       403   +3 IniReadInteger
18ce7838 +04c rxctl140.bpl   rxPlacemnt       805   +2 TFormPlacement.ReadInteger
18ce7c59 +045 rxctl140.bpl   rxPlacemnt       883   +4 TFormPlacement.RestoreFormPlacement
18ce6d71 +029 rxctl140.bpl   rxPlacemnt       517   +3 TFormPlacement.FormShow
5034f185 +015 vcl150.bpl     Forms           3590   +1 TCustomForm.DoShow
5035365d +0a9 vcl150.bpl     Forms           6194  +11 TCustomForm.CMShowingChanged
5027df6c +2d4 vcl150.bpl     Controls        7074  +91 TControl.WndProc
50282830 +568 vcl150.bpl     Controls        9831 +144 TWinControl.WndProc
5034fb28 +594 vcl150.bpl     Forms           3961 +191 TCustomForm.WndProc
5027db90 +024 vcl150.bpl     Controls        6852  +10 TControl.Perform
50281c79 +10d vcl150.bpl     Controls        9475  +19 TWinControl.UpdateShowing
50281d88 +0bc vcl150.bpl     Controls        9510  +21 TWinControl.UpdateControlState
5028496e +026 vcl150.bpl     Controls       11263   +3 TWinControl.CMVisibleChanged
5027df6c +2d4 vcl150.bpl     Controls        7074  +91 TControl.WndProc
50282830 +568 vcl150.bpl     Controls        9831 +144 TWinControl.WndProc
5034fb28 +594 vcl150.bpl     Forms           3961 +191 TCustomForm.WndProc
503511c9 +385 vcl150.bpl     Forms           4764  +50 TCustomForm.SetWindowToMonitor
5027db90 +024 vcl150.bpl     Controls        6852  +10 TControl.Perform
5027c582 +026 vcl150.bpl     Controls        5885   +5 TControl.SetVisible
5034f41e +03a vcl150.bpl     Forms           3696   +8 TCustomForm.SetVisible
5035420f +007 vcl150.bpl     Forms           6574   +1 TCustomForm.Show
5035445f +167 vcl150.bpl     Forms           6643  +28 TCustomForm.ShowModal
18c9254b +0ff dclrx140.bpl   rxPictEdit                TPictEditor.Execute
18c92a6c +0d0 dclrx140.bpl   rxPictEdit                TGraphicPropertyEditor.Edit
20b0407a +142 coreide150.bpl PropInsp         867  +18 TPropertyInspector.PropListEditDblClick
21197c49 +015 vclide150.bpl  IDEInspListBox   619   +2 TInspListBox.DoEditDblClick
21199a7f +01f vclide150.bpl  IDEInspListBox  1310   +2 TInspListBox.ListButtonClick
5027e4d7 +06f vcl150.bpl     Controls        7190   +9 TControl.Click
2118f5de +046 vclide150.bpl  IDEListBtns      584   +8 TListButton.WMLButtonUp
5027df6c +2d4 vcl150.bpl     Controls        7074  +91 TControl.WndProc
50282830 +568 vcl150.bpl     Controls        9831 +144 TWinControl.WndProc
50281ed0 +02c vcl150.bpl     Controls        9552   +3 TWinControl.MainWndProc
500afa64 +014 rtl150.bpl     Classes        13491   +8 StdWndProc
77d189e3 +00a USER32.dll                               DispatchMessageW
50358af7 +0f3 vcl150.bpl     Forms           9760  +23 TApplication.ProcessMessage
50358b3a +00a vcl150.bpl     Forms           9790   +1 TApplication.HandleMessage
50358e65 +0c9 vcl150.bpl     Forms           9927  +26 TApplication.Run
```

After I close the MadExcept log, the Icon designer appears and I can set the icon to the form.

Does anyone got any idea on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the [RxLib 8.0](http://www.dummzeuch.de/delphi/rxlibsf/english.html) TFormPlacement component is registered incorrect into the Delphi IDE, and even it is not used in the project, when the Picture Editor is opened, the component is trying to apply it's behavior to the Picture Editor form.